# HTML5 Pattern Api - No HTML tags - Form Validation

Tags: regex, html, validation

So I love using the html5 pattern api. I want to setup a pattern(regex) that will not allow html tags to be entered into the form. I have a working example of the pattern api below. What regex should I use to stop all html tags?

```
<form onsubmit="alert('Boom!'); return false;">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-1]">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't try to stop people submitting things that look like HTML, just treat the data as text (so replace `<` with `&lt;`, `&` with `&amp;`, and so on when putting the submitted text into an HTML document).

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. But I'm aiming for native html5 validation.

Comment: Distinguishing between HTML and things that look a little bit like HTML is non-trivial and certainly not something I'd leave to a regex.

Comment: i've found `^[^<>]+$` which looks for < and > characters. I'll see how this goes. We have server validation as well, we just want to add one more layer of validation to the site.

Comment: so `<input type="text" pattern="^[^<>]+$">` works well.

Comment: So nobody is allowed to say that `3 > 2`?

Comment: yeah that's an issue. dang. Maybe < alpha characters then > also look for forward slashes.

Comment: `<g>` is an emoticon. `4 / 2 = 2`.

Comment: your right, it's too hard to stop people submitting < and or > characters. Best to convert them and restrict on certain fields like name to alpha characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to stop **any** HTML tags? Easy:

`</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>`

---

You can also match **specific tags** with this regex:

`<specific_tag[^>]*>(.*?)</specific_tag>`